# Convert Offset portion of DateTime based on parameter passed at runtime in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code, ssis, date-formatting

Using SSIS (Script Task), I have a parameter that is being passed that is a number which represents each individual timezone (in this case `01` for `EST`, `02` for `Central` etc.....).

I would like to know if there is a way for me to set the "Offset" portion of a formatted date (ie. `2023-02-13T01:17:38.477-06:00`), based on the timezone being passed at runtime.

Currently I am using a .NET (Vers. 4.7.03062) custom date format that looks like this: `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fff**zzz**`.  The issue with using `**zzz**` is the offset is set based on the system time of the server, instead of being based on the timezone passed at runtime.

Code currently written as

```
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("EventDate", Row.EventDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffzzz"))
```

Current output: `2023-02-13T01:17:38.477-06:00` - Based on system time/location in Central Time zone

Desired output: `2023-02-13T01:17:38.477-05:00` - Based on numerical parameter passed at runtime (01), which represents Eastern Time Zone.

How can I do this?

Comment: For this, you probably want to import the Noda time library.

Comment: Think the real source of your problem is you're trying to manage datetime output as strings.  Dates are format-less.  Treat them as dates, that way you can easily manage local/UTC/Time zone offsets without the issues around string formating

Comment: Unfortunately the client wants their output in a csv file and their date formatted a specific way. Hence the converting the date to string.

Comment: You can tostring a date into any format in the blink of an eye. That's not the actual issue here. You're better off using a date, dateTime, datetimeoffset, etc and manipulate that as needed and then use the tostring to spit out eh string format however you need it.

Comment: Https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-datetimeoffset-ctor(system-datetime-system-timespan) will do what you need.

Comment: Thank you @ClearlyClueless I'll review the link you posted.